# How can Cobalt test HDR implementation

Tags: cobalt

In YouTube home page, when I choose a video in 4K HDR channel, the transfer id is always 'Bt709', no matter the below function returns true or false.

```
[0627/102524:INFO:media_source.cc(322)] MediaSource::IsTypeSupported(video/webm; codecs="vp9"; eotf=bt709)
```

Is there other configuration controlling this? If no, how can we test HDR implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one of the capability checks. In our Technical Requirements document, if you support HDR, we require you to support all of "bt709", "smpte2084", "arib-std-b67". So we expect you to pass that "bt709" query to playback HDR videos.

If you pass "bt709" capability check, you will get another capability check. If you don't support it, return false. Then you will get respective HDR streams that the video has.

Comment: Actually we pass both 'bt709' and 'catavison' check, we still cannot get respective HDR streams. ( test with NHykpuFkKQ8) 

[cobalt]>[0101/010355:INFO:media_source.cc(331)] MediaSource::IsTypeSupported(video/webm; codecs="vp9"; eotf=bt709) -> probably/true
[cobalt]>[0101/010355:INFO:media_source.cc(331)] MediaSource::IsTypeSupported(video/webm; codecs="vp9"; eotf=catavision) -> probably/true

Comment: I find fault that I ignore the opposite check of 'catavison'.  
Thanks for your information.

Comment: Great to hear that!